# Performance of VisualSVN Server

Tags: performance, svn, visualsvn-server

Have anyone witnessed peformance problems using VisalSVN server over a LAN? We get about 300 KB/S when doing update().

Answer (score 3):

We use VisualSVN server over cabled LAN at work (100mbits) with no performance issues. At home I access it via 54g wireless with decent performance too. So it sounds like a network issue.

Try setting up a share and copying files across to see if you achieve similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

I've used SVN over a LAN, and didn't notice any appreciable performance hit, though I was never an administrator.

You may want to re-ask this question over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), since it's really about server administration / performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well! We're running Windows Server 2008. I've done a bunch of tests and it seems that Server 2008 or something has the issue as it seems fairly reasonable on 2003. We've been running SVN over the file system for some time but wanted to move to VisualSVN to support the HTTP protocol but so far unusable on server 2008. It took one of our devs 2 hours to check in 86 MB!

- Running SVN Server on Windows 2008 (Virtual Machine) using a NAS (UNC Path) as storage on port 80 
  Checkout = 1 min 28 seconds CPU ~30%
- Running SVN Server on Windows 2008 (Virtual Machine) using a NAS (UNC Path) as storage on port 8080 
  Checkout = 1 min 28 seconds CPU ~30%
- Running Windows 2008 (Virtual Machine) using local storage & file system based SVN
  Checkout = 48 seconds
- Running SVN Server on Windows 2003 using a NAS (UNC Path) as storage on port 8080
  Checkout = 48 seconds CPU ~6%